# Multiple document.write from external scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL that generates a document.write method that inserts another JS.

Example:

```
http://domain.com/scriptONE.js
```

Generates

```
document.write('http://domain.com/scriptTWO.js');
```

How can I use jQuery to insert the second document.write to a div not an iFrame - so that my div contains only the output from this file

```
http://domain.com/scriptTWO.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.get("http://domain.com/scriptTWO.js", function(data){
    $("#divObjectId").html($("#divObjectId").html()+data);
});
```

I think that I understand your question, if not is this what you want to do, please tell me better what you want to do.

Comment: $.get won't work in his case as the js returns document.write(<script>script.js</script>);

Comment: @Eeyore Ok, but do you have a js file that includes another js file? Because you can use the $.ajax with parameter dataType: "script". More information on http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [writeCapture.js](http://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture) (full disclosure: I'm the author.) The usage in your case would be:

```
$('#myDiv').writeCapture().html('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/scriptONE.js"> </script>');
```

And that's all there is to it. The plugin will take care of loading the other script and capturing the output and inserting it into the div.